# Resetting file/folder permissions when migrating from Win2k to Win2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, permissions, windows-server-2000

I first want to say well done for all the info on this site but I've got a high-level question regarding folder/file permissions that I'm looking to solve in one of the following two ways:

1. Using ICALCS to reset permissions.
2. ASP.net c# web form using builtin FileSecurity api.

You see I'm currently moving all Win2k server webapps to a Win2008 server. The problem is that since were making such a big jump from 2k to 2008, the conversion tools for the migration do not work. That being said, my task is to copy all websites (currently all in one dir) from 2k to 2008 server, somehow save all permissions from 2k and reapply those permissions in 2008. I see that from above the steps are in place to reset the permissions but is there a recommendation as to how I save the permissions from Win2k and then reapply them to the copied files on 2008? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy is capable of copying files with their permissions intact with the /SEC switch.

But I would also point out that there is a very good chance your web applications will *need* different permissions on Windows 2008 (particularly if it's R2) than it did on Windows 2000.  Anonymous accounts and application pool identities work quite a bit differently.